# Cron Job: Got error: connect ECONNREFUSED but not getting the response

Tags: node.js, cron

While running the following code I can get only "Got error: connect ECONNREFUSED". Can any one suggest me, how to get the response from the below one and I am running this as a cron job, while this link is triggered I will get the response from the following.

```
var http = require('http');
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
new CronJob('* * * * * *', function() {
  var url = 'http://localhost:3000/googlefit?email=myhs@gmail.com&token=546546464547fdgdfgdfgdfg';
    http.get(url, function(res) {
        console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);

        res.on("data", function(chunk) {
            console.log("BODY: " + chunk);
        });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    });
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

Comment: On which port, your application is listening ? Should it be `3000` in `var url = 'http://localhost:3000/googlefit` ?

Comment: Yes, it's listening to 3000

Comment: Can you share the code of `server` where application is listening on port `3000` ? Because if you change `var url = 'http://google.com'`, then you won't get `Connection Refused` .

Comment: does it serve a few request and then you get **`Connection Refused `** or is it the first time

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem is the following statement in the cronJob declaration, '* * * * * *', this sends a request every second to the server and the server could get overwhelmed with too many requests than it can handle. Can you the declaration and check again?

Comment: Instead of the above url I have mentioned (var url = 'http://www.google.co.in';), its working fine and get some response from it. I want the cron job to run each and every second so only I mentioned as '* * * * * *'

Comment: Does it run on url = http://localhost:3000/googlefit?email=myhs@gmail.com&token=546546464547fdgdfgdfgdfg without '* * * * * *'?

Answer (score 1):

The above question code itself correct. The problem of not getting the response is the URL runs for a long time so only I cant get response for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with your application `server` code, that's why you are getting `ECONNREFUSED` or Connection Refused.

If you change url to `var url = 'http://www.google.com`, then you would get response. This means that you application is not listening on port 3000.

Kindly check it again.

Comment: Am running the cron job separately and application separately, the url get triggered and run in the application side but I cant get response on the cron job side. The cron job was ideal until the application is running. If I stop the application, then I can get 'connect ECONNREFUSED' in the cron job.

Comment: Do one thing, try to access `http://localhost:3000/googlefit?email=myhs@gmail.com&token=546546464547fdgdfgdfgdfg` in your browser ?

Comment: Kindly see my first comment. Its working fine but I cant get the response in the cron job. From the cron job the url get triggered.

Comment: So, what response do you get ? Is it empty or what ?

Comment: I got the response also, Thanks. The problem I face here is my URL is running so long so only I cant get any response for a long time.

Comment: So, it means that your application is not responding within required time ?

Comment: No no That URL has big process so only its not get response for a long time